# Integrate python scripts in c++ app

Tags: c++, boost-python

I need to extend my c++ app with python scripts but I'm unsure which interface library I should use. The basic communication is: c++ app registers some class methods to the script (so that they could be loaded as module in the script), then calls a specific function in the python script. The script should then perform its task while being able to call the c++ methods. When the script has finished, the c++ app should be able to use the return value of the script (e.g. as a std::list).

From what I've read boost.python is pretty powerful and considering the fact that I already use boost, it seems the way to go. But in the documentation, I have not seen a way to expose class methods (static or not) to the python script.

Is this possible? How can I do that?

**Edit**:

Ok, I think I should have been a little more specific, sorry. I already know about how to import python libraries etc. into my c++ code and I've taken a look into the boost documentation regarding embedding but didn't got what I was looking for.

For clarity, this is the workflow in my scenario:

1. C++ app starts running
2. At some point, a C++ class needs support from a specific python script which is located somewhere at a defined plugin-location on the hard disk.
3. Before calling the script, the C++ class wants to expose some of its methods to the script for callbacks (the script should only be able to call this methods this time, i.e. when the script has finished execution and gets invoked from another place in the c++ app, it should not be able to call the class methods anymore. Also, I don't want to expose the whole class to the script - only the specific methods and the script should not be able to create instances of the class. Furthermore, I don't want that other python scripts are able to call the exposed methods, only the one that I'm going to call.)
4. After "registering" the class methods to the script, the c++ app calls the needed function in the script and gets the return value as a c++ type (e.g. a std::list)

I think the third point is the tricky part here and I've no idea how I can achieve this...

Comment: Yes you can use Boost.Python for that. It's called "embedding" when you embed the Python interpreter as opposed to extending where you write Python modules in C++. Those searchwords should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Absolutely, yes.

> How can I do that?

In the most general sense,

Import python libraries with:

```
boost::python::object obj = boost::python::import("module_name");
```

Access library objects and subobjects and functions with:

```
obj.attr("name");
```

That should be enough to get you going - as you get further, the details are in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/reference.html).

(Example:)

```
auto calendar = boost::python::import( "calendar" );
auto leap = calendar.attr("isleap")("2015");
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but it wasn't exactly what I'm looking for. Please see my edited question.